# Julia sometimes reading wrong values from CSV file

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia

I have a simple .csv (I think) file that was generated by a commercial software program. When I open it in Excel or any other text editor, the data looks fine. However, when I read it with the following Julia code, some of the data changes value. I have uploaded a truncated version of the file linked below. Here the data in the 11th row and 2nd column should be -1670.0, but it is instead read by Julia as 1.84e19. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
using DataFrames, CSV
path=raw"/Users/nathan/Downloads"
filename="MiddlePrincipalStress.csv"
df=CSV.read(joinpath(path,filename),DataFrame,delim='\t')
println(df[10,[2]])
```

```html
<a href=http://www.filedropper.com/middleprincipalstress><img src=http://www.filedropper.com/download_button.png width=127 height=145 border=0/></a><br /><div style=font-size:9px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:127px;font-color:#44a854;> <a href=http://www.filedropper.com >upload files free</a></div>
```

"Download This File" button in the middle of the page is the correct one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Julia sometimes reading wrong values from CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315557/julia-sometimes-reading-wrong-values-from-csv-file)

Comment: This seems to be a bug. I have filed https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/714 for it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry for the duplicates. StackOverflow gave me an error each time I submitted my question. They apparently went through later. I have deleted the others since this was the only one to receive feedback so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update Parsers.jl (or just update packages in your Julia installation). The bug is fixed:

```
julia> CSV.read(IOBuffer("x\n-1670."))
1×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │
│     │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ -1670.0 │
```

You need Parsers.jl in version 1.0.8 for things to work correctly.